# Rails 5/ActiveRecord: Can I avoid N+1 when counting records in another table without declaring an association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a model that returns the count of records in an un-associated model that match a given value:

```
  def number_of_orders
    Order.where(delivery_date: date).size
  end
```

My model has a `date` attribute and I want to find all the orders with a matching date.

My controller looks like this:

```rb
def index
  @schedule_dates = ScheduleDate.where(date: 1.week.ago..Float::INFINITY)
end
```

My problem is that when I call `number_of_orders` in the view, I end up with N+1 queries:

```rb
<% @schedule_dates.each do |date| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= date.number_of_orders %></td>
```

I've tried `includes` in the controller:

```
def index
  @schedule_dates = ScheduleDate.where(date: 1.week.ago..Float::INFINITY).includes(:orders)
end
```

But Rails complains that the association is not found.

Is it possible to avoid N+1 queries without creating an association with the two models?

Comment: Includes won't work because it uses the association thing for include. in this case I think your best option would be using a custom SQL scope to fetch all the counts at once in that query

Answer (score 0):

You can add `has_many` association to `ScheduleDate`

`has_many :orders, foreign_key: 'delivery_date', primary_key: 'date'`

then you can use `includes` in the search query

`@schedule_dates = ScheduleDate.includes(:orders).where(date: 1.week.ago..Float::INFINITY)`

and in the view

```
<% @schedule_dates.each do |date| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= date.orders.length %></td>
```